# which urls to un-block for centOS system setup

Tags: centos, url

I am a newbie to linux system. Our system guy spun up a centOS server with very minimal configuration for me in the data center. For security reason, information security team has outbound internet connections from our data center blocked. Users need to submit requests to have certain url un-blocked before they can be accessed.  This server will be mainly used for some data science work using python, And I should be able to remote log in this server using RDP from my windows based laptop. I am having difficulties to figured out which url(urls) should be included in the list to unblock. for example: I need to have gnome installed as GUI, need to sudo yum install xrdp, install some IDE for python, pip install some python package. Could you please help me to show me the correct direction to go?

Answer (score 0):

For OS related packages you will need to ask them to authorize :

```
http://mirror.centos.org
```

For python related libraries  :

```
http://pypi.python.org
https://pypi.python.org
```

Which is the default python packages index.